# Can I style individual characters in an input?

Tags: html, css

A client has asked to use the type="number" attribute for a credit card field in order to get the right keyboard on mobile devices, but would like some padding after every 4th character to make it look more like a credit card number. Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Credit-Card-Input-Mask-Plugin-Credit-js.html) or [that](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) maybe?

Comment: what about card numbers that aren't 16 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mask input plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) is the best option for that.

```
$('#creditcard').mask('0000 0000 0000 0000');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different separate inputs, all of type 'number', and move focus between them using javascript every time the input meets your criteria (let's say: 4 characters...)